# Change the font-size of a <p> element inside Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jumbotron, which has a placeholder on top to handle errors on the page. The error has a `<p>` tag with its own class, and I want to modify the size of the element. However, the in-built paragraph styles of the jumbotron (Bootstrap) seem to override whatever I've set. I don't want to change the global `<p>` size, just of this particular element.

HTML:

```
    <div class='jumbotron'>

         <div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert' id= "landing-page-error">
          <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' aria-hidden='true'>  </span>
<p class = "error-message"> Sign-Up Error </p>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#landing-page-error {
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; /* this and the position: absolute has the error message pop up right below the header nav bar in landing page */
 height: 10%;
}

.error-message {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

It's a Rails app, and here's a screenshot of the CSS inside the browser -

[image]

Please help me set the size of the `<p>` tag specifically for the error element. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.jumbotron .error-message {
    font-size: 14px;
```

}

if this doesn't work, then try this:

```
.jumbotron p.error-message {
        font-size: 14px;
}
```

it will effect all the `error-messages` inside `jumbotron` without affecting other `<p>` tags inside your page.

Comment: Thanks Deepak, this worked! I'm curious as to why just the pure class of the p tag didnt work.

Comment: HI @KeshavVasudevan there is a term called **CSS Specifity** This is responsible how our `CSS` works. Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

Nothing Problem just close the Div class before P tag

```
     <div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert' id=    "landing-page-error">
      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign' aria-hidden='true'>  </span> </div>
 <p class = "error-message"> Sign-Up Error </p>
```

Comment: No, I want the error message inside the div, but thank you for taking time to answer